# How might one implement cat with sed?

Tags: sed, cat

I'm considering removal from `/usr/bin/` of Ubuntu 20.04 on my Laptop such utilities as like `cat`, `head`, `tail`, and `wc` in order to force myself to get more experience with `sed` and `awk` and to learn these two really well . How might I implement `cat` with `sed` as a one-liner to be used interactively (from the CLI)?

Comment: Why would you want to use the wrong tools for your tasks? Rather use the appropriate tools and give yourself some tasks where `sed` is the best tool.

Comment: `cat` does more than just blindly dumping out files. For example, `cat -v` replaces non-printable characters with something printable. It might be possible to do that with `sed`, but it's not trivial. Have a look at the manual page of `cat`.

Comment: @berndbausch that's [not POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html) though.

Comment: @roaima Yes but Linux is not called GNU/Linux for nothing, and OP has Ubuntu.

Comment: @pLumo So that I can compare the tools at my disposal e.g. `time` tell me that `cat file` is the right tool as it has shorter runtime than both `sed '' file` and `awk 1 file`.
It is also to force me to develop a `cat`-independent skill in the same way as removal of a GUI-based file manager forced me to learn `lf`(a TUI file manager).

Comment: Removing things from /usr/bin to "force" yourself to do something ?? You may want to read up on self-motivation. Meanwhile, you are probably going to break many system scripts that depend on these tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` is a stream editor, i.e. it reads from *stdin* or named files, performs some edits, and writes to *stdout*. If you don't perform any edits then it will act much like `cat` - but not exactly the same in all circumstances.

```
sed [-e] '' [<files...>]
```

`awk` is good for pattern scanning and processing. If you give it nothing to do it will also act mostly like `cat` - but not exactly the same in all circumstances.

```
awk 1 [<files...>]
```

Comment: `head` --> `sed '1q' file`; `tail` -->  `sed -n '$p file`. However, I don't see any benefit, that won't help you learn `sed`.

Comment: or  `sed '1q' file` ;-)

Comment: Except that `awk` and `sed` are  text utilities and accepts only text (with the behaviour varying between implementations when the input is non-text; awk accepts file without a trailing newline but will add one back) while `cat` will be able to concatenate non-text files without mangling them.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas fundamentally this question is about trying to use the wrong tool for the job. If you have a knife it will act much like a screwdriver too, but I wouldn't recommend that either

Answer (score -2):

Any of the following lines seem to implement `cat` with `sed`:

```
sed $(sed -n $= /home/jerzy/.bitcoin/debug.log)q /home/jerzy/.bitcoin/debug.log
```

```
sed `sed -n $= /home/jerzy/.bitcoin/debug.log`q /home/jerzy/.bitcoin/debug.log
```

Comment: That's a Rube Goldberg way of doing this. `sed`'s default is to print all lines, just like `cat`, so just don't do anything (`sed '' /some/file`) and it will happily do what `cat` does.

Comment: @muru Darn, and all this time I've been typing `sed '/.*/n' /some/file` :)